# Make half of UIView go out of screen

Tags: ios, uiview

I created a floating view for my application which always displays on screen.

Now I want to make a half of it go outside my screen when it is interactive for 3-4 seconds. I think I should use a `NSTimer` to hide out this view, but it is not the problem.

The problem is how should I set `origin.x` of this view to go outside of the screen? I've tried to set the frame in my `initWithSuperView` like this:

```
CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
CGFloat screenX = screenRect.origin.x;
[self setFrame:CGRectMake(-screenX - size.width, 0, size.width, size.height)];
```

However, it doesn't work. How should I do it to get my desired result? See image below for more information:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use uiview animation similar to this:

```
dispatch_async(mainQueue, ^{
    __weak __typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:3.f animations:^{
        // change uiview frame here
        weakSelf.frame = hiddenFrame;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        // setup completion
        [weakSelf.view layoutIfNeeded];
    }];
});
```

also you can setup `NSLayoutConstraint` to the x constraint of uiview and update it with negative value when you need.

Comment: why dispatch_async - mainQueue?

Comment: @Ahmad Because UI operations must be provided just only on the main thread.

Comment: :) animateWithDuration does NOT block the main thread. it's not like downloading an image -for example- on a separated queue and reflects the result to a UI component in the main thread. Try it by yourself.

Comment: I provided this example just from my project. And on another thread I sent requests to server with AFNetw.. 

For animateWithDuration:, the class reference doesn't say anything about threading, so I am not sure.

Comment: So I don't need dispatch_async block for this case, right?

Comment: The Ahmad did not gave some proofs, so do as you see fit.